# OpenCV solvePnP method returns NaN values

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, zbar, pose-estimation

I'm doing barcode detection using `zbar` library with `opencv` in C++. The barcode detection is working good and I'm getting results like that

---

[image: result]

---

Now I want to use `cv::solvePnP` to get the pose of my camera (already calibrated). As 3D points I'm using a template in which, at program start, I compute the same barcode detection and I take the top left corner and bottom right corner. I then compute the world coordinates of these two points with respect to the center of the barcode in this way:

```
(pt.x - imageSize.width / 2) * px_to_mm,
(pt.y - imageSize.height / 2) * px_to_mm,
0.
```

`imageSize` is the size of the barcode (in pixels), `px_to_mm` is the ratio "length in meters of the barcode height divided by the total number of pixel of the barcode height" and `pt` is the point (either top left or bottom right).

The template is

---

[image: template]

---

I checked that the resulting point of the barcode detection are correct. The world coordinates are `top_left =[0.054160003, 0.025360001, 0], bottom_right = [0.085200004, 0.046080004, 0]`. I assume that these are correct since the dimensions in pixels of the barcode are `388 x 200` and the height in meters is `0.016`.

---

When I run `cv::solvePnP` I get these results

```
translation: [-nan, -nan, -nan] 
rotation: [-nan, nan, -nan;
           -nan, -nan, nan;
           nan, -nan, -nan]
```

The input of the method are the two image points of the barcode detection and the two world points computed using the template. What is the problem?

Comment: two image points? AFAIK it should be at least 4 points for most of the PnP algorithms (I think one of them accepts 3). Read the [note](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d) to see the points needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As api55 said in his comment the problem was the number of points. Adding the other 2 corners worked.